# target to iframe to be same page opening in a new tab in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a form tag and submit to same page with an iframe target, but after submit it is opening in new tab.What should be done to have same page , means what should be the target set for the iframe .

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This tends to happen when the name of the target and the name of the `iframe` don't match.  Here's a working example:

```
<form target="myframe" method="get" action="http://www.google.com">
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="q" value="hello"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </p>
</form>

<p>
    <iframe name="myframe" src="" />
</p>
```

See it live at http://jsfiddle.net/Z3AwM/

Make sure the `name` attribute of the `iframe` is set, otherwise it will default to a new window or tab.